# Add category in HighCharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

1. How can I add a new category with data in  basic column chart in highcharts. ([sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-basic/) and code below) Add an other category say 2013 after dec and add all 4 series data with say 50 in that.
2. Add another series to the newly added category with a value of 60 but it should not appear in previous categories.
3. I want to do it dynamically after chart is drawn in some function

---

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To add new categories, you need to use `chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(array)` where `array` contains all categories – old and new ones, not only new.

To add new series use `chart.addSeries(options)`, and for `options` you should have `data: [ [categoryIndex, value] ]` – that will add one point for a specific category.

References:

- [setCategories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setCategories%28%29)
- [addSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

1. Add `2013` to `xAxis.categories`, then add `50` to the end of each `series.data`
2. Add a new serie `f` and give with `[0, 0, ..., 60]` as `data`
3. The chart is already "dynamic" (call `$('#container').highcharts(options);` to draw

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/FRjVV/1/)

Comment: No i want to do that dynamically after chart is drawn i want to call a function and then add a new category with data

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/VYDDH/

I did changes at

```
xAxis: {
    categories: [
        'Jan',
        'Feb',
        'Mar',
        'Apr',
        'May',
        'Jun',
        'Jul',
        'Aug',
        'Sep',
        'Oct',
        'Nov',
        'Dec',
        '2013'
    ]
},
```

and

```
series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4,50]
    }, {
        name: 'New York',
        data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3,50]
    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2,50]
    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1,50]
}]
```

Are you trying to get this this?

Comment: No i want to do that dynamically after chart is drawn i want to call a function and then add a new category with data